# Disable WebView's Embedded Video feature in Android 4.X devices

Tags: javascript, android, webview, youtube-api

Recently I faced a problem with **Youtube** videos (`iframe API`) in WebView of **Android 4.X** devices.

The problem is `onShowCustomView()` not fired when video starts playing on Android 4.X devices. I searched for reason, why `onShowCustomView()` not fired? I got answer as in Android 4.X devices WebView has a feature Embedded Video, because of this video ( in HTML5) will be played by WebView and won't display the video in other Layout.

But when user requested Full Screen mode, then `onShowCustomView()` will be fired.

Actually I need the Full screen mode of youtube video by default, In Youtube's iframe API no such option to enter full screen, user has to press full screen button.

**So for my requirement only 2 answers are there.**

1. Disbaling of Embedded Video for my WebView, then it will work like below Android 4.X and onShowCustomView() will be fired.
2. Setting the full screen mode by default with Javascript in html file supplying to WebView.

So If anybody got solution to my problem please help me otherwise suggest me to solve this.